# Collapsible Section in Android standard

Tags: android

Is there any standard option available to create a collapsible section with android satndard SDK. In which we can have a normal clickable header which will show or hide some section.

Thanks in Advance,
Kaushik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, you can use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), and see this sample here:
[How To Get Started With ExpandableListView](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/270612-how-to-get-started-with-expandablelistview/)